# Java - Windows MMC - Private key is null for a certificate when a different user is logged in

Tags: java

I have installed a pfx certificate file in Windows Trusted store with a Master user. Then I have switched the user to a standard user and accessed the certificate from JAVA. But the certificate's private key is null.
I think it may be a permission issue.Please help me. But for the same user(here master user) the certificate is having private key and my RMI over SSL connection passes.

I am not able to pass RMI connection over SSL because of this issue.Handshake failure message is coming.

Comment: If it was _not_ null then the standard user could pretend to BE the master user ... so - for me that's expected and *wanted* behavior.

Comment: But the standard user dont know the master user password, and it cannot be done.

Comment: Is it the standard behavior that if a user installs a certificate, its private key is not accessible by any other user in the machine? Then what "Local computer" in windows certificate store means? In my understanding, if we are installing a certificate in "Local computer" that certificate will be fully accessible by all other users in the machine.Please clarify me.